# Safe implicit value validation: $H_k(k \oplus m) \sim H_k(m)$?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, keys, symmetric, authentication

$H_k$ is a cryptographic hash function that's keyed using a section of key material $k$ *(for whatever definition of "keyed" that's appropriate for the given hash function $H$)*.

1. Are the following two methods roughly equivalent ways of authenticating that the section of key material $k$ is associated with the section of message material $m$?

$$H_k(k \oplus m) \tag{a}$$
$$H_k(m) \tag{b}$$

2. Is there anything wrong with choosing one method over the other?

<sub>***Note:** The goal isn't to show knowledge of $m$ or prove security of the scheme. The questions are only concerned with how interchangeable the methods are with regard to associating $k$ and $m$.*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Are the following two methods roughly equivalent ways of authenticating that the section of key material $k$ is associated with the section of message material $m$?
>    $$H_k(k \oplus m) \tag{a}$$
>    $$H_k(m) \tag{b}$$

The question of association in this context isn't well-defined. It would be better to ask questions which clearly identify the problem to be solved, & which satisfy some useful security notion if answered appropriately. Let's try asking some better questions.

**Preliminaries:**
$$\epsilon_a = F_a(k, m) = H_k(k \oplus m)$$
$$\epsilon_b = F_b(k, m) = H_k(m)$$
$$\epsilon_{a, b} = F_{a, b}(k, m) = (\epsilon_a, \epsilon_b)$$

---

$\quad \boldsymbol\alpha$. *In the locations where these procedures occur, can any other values $k'$ ***or*** $m'$ result in the evaluation of either $\epsilon_a = F_a(k', m')$ ***or*** $\epsilon_b = F_b(k', m')$ being true?*

This question is better, because if the answer is ***no***, then association is defined as a unique evaluation $\epsilon_{a,b} = F_{a,b}(k', m')$ ***iff*** $(k', m') = (k, m)$. Which means, no other values for $k$ or $m$ will satisfy the association.

So, $(\textrm a)$ & $(\textrm b)$ could be considered *"roughly equivalent"* ***iff*** they both have unique $\epsilon_{a, b} \space \forall (k, m)$. But, this cannot be true, because the pigeonhole principle<sup>([0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle))</sup> ensures a hashing function will have output collisions for arbitrary inputs.

The security notion provided by being able to answer question $\boldsymbol\alpha$ in the **negative** is not satisfied.

---

$\quad \boldsymbol\beta$. *In the locations where these procedures occur, is finding any other values $k'$ ***or*** $m'$, given $(k, m, \epsilon_{a, b})$, resulting in either $\epsilon_a = F_a(k', m')$ ***or*** $\epsilon_b = F_b(k', m')$ being true, as hard as finding a *second-preimage*<sup>([1](https://lib.fbtuit.uz/assets/files/00katz-J.LindellY.Introductiontomoderncryptography.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A58%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22FitH%22%7D%2C670%5D))</sup> in $H$?*

This question tries to capture a looser notion of unique association than $\boldsymbol\alpha$ does, by instead tying the *difficulty* of finding any $k'$ ***or*** $m'$ which result in any matching $\epsilon_a$ ***or*** $\epsilon_b$ given $(k, m, \epsilon_{a, b})$ to the *difficulty* of finding a *second-preimage* in the hash function.

Even this looser notion of association isn't generally satisfied for the $(\textrm a)$ & $(\textrm b)$ procedures. It ***depends*** on the ***hashing function***, the ***keying*** & message ***ingestion*** procedures, as well as the data ***representations***. For example, if the hash function & keying procedure is $\textrm{HMAC-SHA256}$, with *as-is* message ingestion & little-endian byte representations, then trivial *second-preimages* can be found for input tuples $(k', m') \neq (k, m)$ where $\epsilon'_{a, b} = \epsilon_{a, b}$.

This is essentially possible because, given distinct input values, ***xor*** muddles the lengths of each input, & ***xor*** isn't collision resistant on multiple arbitrary inputs. $\textrm{HMAC-SHA256}$ too uses ***xor*** internally to encode the key, allowing trivial *second-preimages* in the input $k$, described as follows:

\begin{equation}
\forall \space (k, m) 
\quad H\textrm{.blocksize} \gt |k| \ge |m|
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ell = H\textrm{.blocksize} - |k|
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F_a(k, m) = 
F_a(k', m') = 
H_{
  k || \underbrace{0 \ldots 0}_{n \space \le \space \ell}
}(
  (k || \overbrace{0 \ldots 0}^{n \space \le \space \ell}) 
  \oplus
  (m || 
    \overbrace{0 \ldots\ldots\ldots 0}^{
      n' \space\le\space |k| + n - |m| \space
    }
  )
)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F_b(k, m) = 
F_b(k', m) = 
H_{k || \underbrace{0 \ldots 0}_{n}}(m)
\end{equation}

The following Python code is a proof of concept, showing $(k', m') \neq (k, m)$ where $\epsilon_a = F_a(k', m')$ and $\epsilon_b = F_b(k', m)$.

```
import math
import hmac
import secrets
import hashlib

ZERO = b"\x00"
ORDER = "little"
H = hashlib.sha256
BLOCKSIZE = H().block_size

as_int = lambda x: int.from_bytes(x, ORDER)
as_bytes = lambda x: x.to_bytes(math.ceil(x.bit_length() / 8), ORDER)
xor = lambda x, y: as_bytes(as_int(x) ^ as_int(y))
F_a = lambda k, m: hmac.new(k, xor(k, m), H).digest()
F_b = lambda k, m: hmac.new(k, m, H).digest()

k = secrets.token_bytes(32); assert BLOCKSIZE > len(k)
m = b"message"; assert len(k) > len(m)
a = F_a(k, m)
b = F_b(k, m)

assert all(
    a == F_a(k + i*ZERO, m + i*ZERO)
    for i in range(len(k) - len(m))
)
assert all(
    b == F_b(k + i*ZERO, m)
    for i in range(BLOCKSIZE - len(k))
)
```

Clearly, the association notion based on $\boldsymbol\beta$'s reliance on the *second-preimage resistance* of the *collision-resistant* $H$ cannot be achieved if the inputs aren't at least sufficiently canonically encoded. It's also clear that the answer to question ***1.*** is ***no***, $(\textrm a)$ & $(\textrm b)$ are ***not*** roughly equivalent, as each procedure introduces distinct issues for the purposes of uniquely associating $k$ & $m$.

The code below offers an example of input canonicalization which could help in making $(\textrm a)$ & $(\textrm b)$ more interchangeable.

```
as_bytes = lambda x, size: x.to_bytes(size, ORDER)
measure = lambda x: len(x).to_bytes(8, ORDER)
measured = lambda x: measure(x) + x
measured_xor = lambda x, y: (
    measure(x)
    + measure(y)
    + as_bytes(as_int(x) ^ as_int(y), size=max([len(x), len(y)]))
)
F_a = lambda k, m: hmac.new(measured(k), measured_xor(k, m), H).digest()
F_b = lambda k, m: hmac.new(measured(k), measured(m), H).digest()
a = F_a(k, m)
b = F_b(k, m)

assert not any(
    a == F_a(k, m + i*ZERO)
    for i in range(1, len(k) - len(m))
)
assert not any(
    b == F_b(k + i*ZERO, m)
    for i in range(1, BLOCKSIZE - len(k))
)
```

---

> 2. Is there anything wrong with choosing one method over the other?

The $(\textrm a)$ procedure requires a bit more effort to safely process inputs, & $(\textrm b)$ is therefore a bit simpler to use. In neither case is it trivial, as the specifics of the keying procedure, the hash function, the message ingestion, & the data representation impact the overall requirements of associating the inputs $k$ & $m$ under useful notions.